# Load content into div with iframes or javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, iframe

I'm building a site for my band. I have the main page completed. I'd like to load the other pages into the center div, #center_content without changing/reloading anything else on the page. Should I do this with iframes? JavaScript? PHP? I'm not experienced in any of those, but they seem to be my options. Which one would be best and could someone provide a starting point or link to a tutorial that would fit what I'm trying to do?

Here's my site so far:
http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v410/justice4all_quiet/ScreenShot2012-08-23at22259PM.png

Here's a jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/BRPNM/

Comment: AJAX. Research jQuery and AJAX

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to reload anything else on the page?  Don't you want to be found by search engines?  Crawlers don't generally run JavaScript, and iframes are problematic, as crawlers find them and folks often get linked to the inner page without your navigation.  Due to caching, it isn't much of a burden to render your header and what not on subsequent page hits.  Alternatively, have all of your content on a single page and switch what is visible with your navigation.  I wouldn't do it this way though.

Comment: I'd probably recommend not doing what you're asking about with regards to loading your content onto the same page. This technique works well for things like search results pages but not for individual website pages. The reason for this is that search engines like Google much prefer to crawl regular pages on a website which have nice keyword heavy page titles or directory names, I'd recommend looking in to PHP includes which would let you have a separate header, footer etc which you can reference on every page which will cut down on maintenance of your site. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

If the center content is small, then you could load all the content in one single page, then use inline navigation to show/hide the relevant parts. This is how I do it on this basic site (check out the right hand side buttons):
http://usermanagedsolutions.com

If the center content is important, then why would you not load a full page? With a good design, the parts that are common to all pages will be cached, and loading a new page won't take much longer than just loading the center content.

Answer (score 0):

If by "loading pages" you mean loading certain contents (like "about", "photos"), you can have all your content loaded but invisible (in divs set to `display:none;`) and show these divs using jQuery `.show()`.

You can check how .show works here -see the demo-: http://api.jquery.com/show/ (you could also use `.animate()` to give the contents some effects).

This way your info will be indexed by search engines. You could also do it using only CSS, but in this case JS would be quicker and cleaner.